# Nested For Loops error in python

Tags: python, pandas, nested, ipython, knn

trying to implement KNN classifier using euclidean distance manually wrote two types of code one is giving the correct result and the other is giving completely a different picture can anyone help me with the difference and where have I committed the mistake?

First Code ( which worked):

```
def squared_dist(x,y):
    return np.sum(np.square(x-y))

def my_classifier(x):
    distances = [squared_dist(x,train_data[i,]) for i in range(len(train_labels))]
    index = np.argmin(distances)
    return train_labels[index]

[my_classifier(test_data[i,]) for i in range(len(test_data))]
```

the above line gave me the exact predictions

second code (which didn't work):

wanted to implement both the for loops in a single line so wrote it like

```
def my_classifier2(x):
    distances = [squared_dist(x[j,],train_data[i,]) for j in range(len(test_labels)) for i in range(len(train_labels))]
    index = np.argmin(distances)
    return train_labels[index]

my_classifier2(test_data)
```

The above code gave an error 
**index 2492731 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7500**

can any one explain me whats going wrong in the second code and how to fix it ?

Comment: in the 2nd one you have 'test_labels'.. is this correct?

Comment: Ya test data and test labels are of the same size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first code, the `distances` list will only contain `len(train_labels)` elements. In your second code however, `distances` will have `len(train_labels)*len(test_labels)` elements because you put in it all pairwise distances between all rows in `train_data` and `test_data`. Therefore, the index from `np.argmin` may exceed the length of `train_labels`.

Here is how you might fix it

```
def my_classifier2(x):
    distances = [[squared_dist(x[j,],train_data[i,]) for i in range(len(train_labels))] for j in range(len(test_labels))]

    indices = np.argmin(distances, axis=1)
    return train_labels[indices]
```

Now `distances` will contain `len(test_labels)` rows. Each row is a list of `len(train_labels)` distance values between the corresponding test data point and all train data points.

The `np.argmin` with `axis=1` will find the min index for each row. Finally, `train_labels[indices]` gives you an array of `len(test_labels)` elements of the final results.

**Update**

Let's say you have 5 train examples:

```
[[a, a, a],
 [b, b, b],
 [c, c, c],
 [d, d, d]]
```

And 2 test examples:

```
 [[x, x, x]
  [y, y, y]]
```

In the first code, your function `my_classifier` only processes one test example at a time. For example, when you call `my_classifier([x, x, x])`, you have:

```
distances = [xa, xb, xc, xd]
```

When I say `xa`, it means the distance between [x, x, x] and [a, a, a]. Here `distances` has `len(train_labels)` elements.

For the second code, your code produces

```
distances = [xa, xb, xc, xd, ya ,yb ,yc, yd]
```

Whereas it should be

```
distances = [[xa, xb, xc, xd],
             [ya, yb, yc, yd]]
```

Now `distances` has 2 rows (`len(test_labels)`), each has 4 elements (`len(train_labels)`). When you apply `np.argmin` with `axis=1` on this `distances`, you'll get

```
indices = [i1, i2]
```

Where `i1` is the min index of the first row and `i2` is the min index of the second row. When you give `indices` to `train_labels`, it will pick out `[train_labels[i1], train_labels[i2]]`, which is the answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering... there are small doubts if u can answer them 
previously in the fisrt code the distances are equal to the len(train_labels)
but as per your explaination after the second code distances is equal to len(test_labels) so got a little confused can you answer and explain this for me

Comment: when I save the output and run it is showing the len of the output as 1 so can you say me how to fix it

Comment: I've just updated the answer for your first comment. I'm not sure about why you have output of length 1. What are the shapes of your `test_data` and `train_data` arrays?

Comment: hi I am a newbie in learning python ...
thanks for the help one last question
Iam getting the output in the below format
array[0,1,2,3] for ex
what to do if i want the output in the format below
[0,

1,

2,

3] ... its not clearly showing in the comment but line by line rather than a matrix form

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. There are 2 ways I can think of: let's say your array is `a`, then you can either do `a = a[:, np.newaxis]` or `a = np.array([a]).T`. The first way adds a new axis directly to `a`, the second way makes `a` a row in a 2d matrix then transpose.